# What is Suspended exception NullPointerException (Full error in post) and how do I fix it

Tags: java, eclipse

I am did not use any external libraries and am trying to solve the following error:

> Game (4) [Java Application]
>       com.pipelinegaming.pixelproblem.Game at localhost:50673
>           Thread [AWT-EventQueue-0] (Running) 
>           Thread [Display] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))   
>               Sprite.load() line: 25  
>               Sprite.(int, int, int, SpriteSheet) line: 18  
>               Sprite.() line: 9   
>               Screen.render() line: 40    
>               Game.render() line: 137 
>               Game.run() line: 97 
>               Thread.run() line: 745  
>           Thread [DestroyJavaVM] (Running)
>       /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java 
> (May 10, 2015, 3:11:03 PM)

Game Class:

```
package com.pipelinegaming.pixelproblem;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.pipelinegaming.pixelproblem.graphics.Screen;
import com.pipelinegaming.pixelproblem.input.Keyboard;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static int width = 300;
    public static int height = width /16 * 9;
    public static int scale = 3;
    public static String title = "Pixel Problem";
    private Keyboard key;
    private Screen screen;
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;
    private JFrame frame;
    private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height,               
    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);  
    private int[] pixels =    
    ((DataBufferInt)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    public Game() {
        screen = new Screen(width, height);
        frame = new JFrame();

        Dimension size = new Dimension(width * scale, height * scale);
        setPreferredSize(size);
        key = new Keyboard();
        frame.addKeyListener(key);
    }
    public synchronized void start() {

        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this, "Display");
        thread.start();










    }
    public synchronized void stop(){
        running = false;

        try{

            thread.join();

        }catch(InterruptedException e){

            e.printStackTrace();


        }




    }
    public void run(){
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
            long sec = System.currentTimeMillis();
            final double ns = 1000000000.0 / 60.0;
            double delta = 0;
            int frames = 0;
            int ticks = 0;
            while (running) {
                long now = System.nanoTime();
                delta = delta + (now - lastTime) / ns;
                lastTime = now;
                while(delta >= 1) {

                    tick();
                    ticks++;
                    delta--;



                }

                render();
                frames++;
                if(System.currentTimeMillis() - sec > 1000) {
                    sec += 1000;
                    frame.setTitle(title + "        |       " + "Tps: " + ticks + " Fps: " + frames);
                    ticks = 0;
                    frames = 0;

                }
            }
            stop();
        }
    public void tick() {
        key.update();






    }
    public void render() {
        BufferStrategy buffer = getBufferStrategy();
        if(buffer == null){

            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;

        }
        for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++){


            pixels[i] = screen.pixels[i];


        }
        Graphics g = buffer.getDrawGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);

        screen.clear();
        screen.render();






        g.dispose();
        buffer.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.frame.setResizable(false);
        game.frame.setTitle(Game.title);
        game.frame.add(game);
        game.frame.pack();
        game.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        game.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        game.frame.setVisible(true);
        game.start();

    }
}
```

Screen Class:

```
package com.pipelinegaming.pixelproblem.graphics;

import java.util.Random;

public class Screen {
private int height, width;
public int [] pixels;
public final int MAP_SIZE = 8;
public final int MAP_SIZE_MASK = MAP_SIZE - 1;
int [] tiles = new int[MAP_SIZE * MAP_SIZE];
public Screen(int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    pixels = new int [width * height];

    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE * MAP_SIZE; i++){
        tiles [i] = random.nextInt(0xffffff);


    }

}
public void clear() {

    for(int i = 1; i < 64 * 64; i++){
        pixels[i] = 0;



    }



}
public void render() {

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
            pixels[x+y*width] = Sprite.main_page_background.pixels[(x & 15) +      
 (y & 15) * Sprite.main_page_background.SIZE];




        }




    }


   }
   }
```

Keyboard Class (Not Used):

```
package com.pipelinegaming.pixelproblem.input;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Keyboard implements KeyListener{
private boolean [] keys = new boolean[120];
public boolean up, down, left, right;

public void update() {
    left = keys[KeyEvent.VK_LEFT] || keys[KeyEvent.VK_A];
    right = keys[KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT] || keys[KeyEvent.VK_D];
    up = keys[KeyEvent.VK_UP] || keys[KeyEvent.VK_W];
    down = keys[KeyEvent.VK_DOWN] || keys[KeyEvent.VK_S];
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
        if(keys[i]) {
        System.out.println("Key: " + i);
        }



    }
}


public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {


}


public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true;

}


public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false;

}





























}
```

SpriteSheet Class:

```
package com.pipelinegaming.pixelproblem.graphics;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class SpriteSheet {
public String path;
public final int SIZE;
public int[] pixels;
public static SpriteSheet all = new     
SpriteSheet("/textures/AllSpriteSheet.png", 256);
public SpriteSheet(String path, int size){
    this.path = path;
    SIZE = size;
    pixels = new int[SIZE * SIZE];
    load();



}
private void load() {
    try {
        BufferedImage image =   
ImageIO.read(SpriteSheet.class.getResource(path));
        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();
        image.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, pixels, 0, w);
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }






}









}
```

Sprite Class:

```
package com.pipelinegaming.pixelproblem.graphics;

public class Sprite {
public final int SIZE;
public int x, y;
public int [] pixels;
public SpriteSheet sheet;

public static Sprite main_page_background = new Sprite(16, 0, 1,      
SpriteSheet.all);


public Sprite (int size, int x, int y, SpriteSheet sheet){

    SIZE = size;
    pixels = new int [SIZE * SIZE];
    this.x = x * size;
    this.y = y * size;
    load();



}
private void load(){
    for (int x = 0; x < SIZE; x++){
        pixels[x + y * SIZE] = sheet.pixels[(x + this.x) + (y + this.y) *   
sheet.SIZE];






    }




}


}
```

I am a begginer to Java progarming but know some other languages, and I would really apreiciate it if someone could please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the NullPointerException is being caused by the line in the Sprite Class:

```
pixels[x + y * SIZE] = sheet.pixels[(x + this.x) + (y + this.y) *   
sheet.SIZE];
```

Because you are trying to reference a property in "sheet" (`sheet.pixels[x + y * SIZE]`) before the object is initialized.

You can solve this either by passing the sheet value from the constructor to load() or by initializing the sheet object using the given value like so:

```
this.y = y * size;
load();
```

Becomes:

```
this.y = y * size;
this.sheet = sheet;
load();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have encountered NullPointerException in load() method Sprite class:

It appears, **sheet.SIZE** throws exception; as you are invoking method on a null object. Take care of Object creation, initialization before you perform invocations.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @RedEyedGrassMan - Have you understood and tried to fix your problem?

Comment: @RedEyedGrassMan - Does it help? Have you tried to fix problem?